# superimpose two images in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

I want to make panorama images using opencv c++.
I can stitch two images together but after stitching two images there is a black region.
One way is to crop the image so there is no longer black pixels and then I can repeat the process, but since the output image is not rectangle by cropping we loose some part of the image.
Second way that came to my mind is that transform third image and then write a function that check which pixel has values bigger than zero and put that value in the final image.
Here is the function that I wrote:

```
Mat SuperImpose(Mat ADDedImage, Mat inputImg) {

    for (int i = 0;i < ADDedImage.rows;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < ADDedImage.cols;j++)
        
        {
            if ((int)inputImg1.at<Vec3b>(i, j).val[2] > 0 || (int)inputImg1.at<Vec3b>(i, j).val[1] > 0 || (int)inputImg1.at<Vec3b>(i, j).val[0] > 0)
            {
                ADDedImage.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = inputImg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
                ADDedImage.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = inputImg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
                ADDedImage.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = inputImg.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2];

            }
        }
    }
}
return ADDedImage;
```

}
It works but there is one issue.
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: final image]

here you can see the two input images and the final output. in the final output there is a black stripe in the borders of the two images which I dont know why happen. How can I fix? is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe because of the if condition.

Comment: this is called "stitching", and what you seem to need is the "blending" part of the whole procedure (see the black seam between pictures?). please investigate the `stitching` module of OpenCV.

Comment: It is our project, i should implement it manually@ChristophRackwitz